# Bad CRC-32 for file '[Content_Types].xml'

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

I am writing a script to parse a dataframe from an html page, when it finds the right criteria, it extracts that specific row and writes it to excel, however, I am getting the error produced below which has be boggled, as the code seems to run properly but I can't open the file.

The source file, and the write directory are both not in .zip format.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook

file = r'...file.html'
table = pd.read_html(file)

wb = Workbook()

i = 1

df1 = table[0]

for index in df1.index:
    activity = df1.iat[index,0]
    i = i + 1
    if activity == "Sample":
         row = index + 1
         df2 = df1.loc[[row]]
         name = "Sample.xlsx"
         writer = pd.ExcelWriter(name)
         df.to_excel(name)
         writer.save()
         read_df = pd.read_excel(name)
```

Error Log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\PycharmProjects\Row Iteration and parsing {Tools}\main.py", line 27, in <module>
    read_df = pd.read_excel(name)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 336, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1131, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 475, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 391, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 486, in load_workbook
    return load_workbook(
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 276, in read
    self.read_manifest()
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 134, in read_manifest
    src = self.archive.read(ARC_CONTENT_TYPES)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1464, in read
    return fp.read()
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 908, in read
    buf += self._read1(self.MAX_N)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1012, in _read1
    self._update_crc(data)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 940, in _update_crc
    raise BadZipFile("Bad CRC-32 for file %r" % self.name)
zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file '[Content_Types].xml'
```

Comment: have you got the solution? I am still getting the same issue but no solution